# Is there some way to do something similar to startForeground for an activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I finally finished my app, but it doesn't work properly on my phone - it seems that the app is always being re-created when I open it after the device has been put to sleep, which (in spite of my best efforts) causes a LOT of trouble for me.

Looking for a way to prevent the app from being killed, I came across `startForeground`... which, as I understand it, applies *only to services* (if not, I can't figure out how to apply it to an Activity - I've tried).

Is there an option which will save me from having to make a lot of serious changes? (I barely understand what I've done so far as it is...)

I've read somewhere that having an ongoing notification work, or worked until froyo - I'm not even sure.
If this is true, would I have to be concerned about the energy consumption? I am using an `AlarmManager` with a partial wake lock on the `BroadcastReciever`, so until the alarm is fired, I don't actually need to be doing anything - just keeping the app alive.

Comment: Why is your app being killed? Are you closing it? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @ChrisStillwell No idea. Not closing it, and no errors (I suspect. No errors on the emulator, doesn't display anything when running it on the phone. can't debug through the phone though).

Comment: So you just start it, look at activity (ui) and suddenly it disappears?

Comment: @Lingviston oh, god. usually I work very hard to make sure I explain myself clearly. I'm sorry - when I put the device to sleep and then wake it up again and open my app, it's being re-created.

Comment: But that's a normal behavior. I need to design your app the way it can work after recreation.

Comment: @Lingviston Yes, I know, and I've tried, and failed. The only other solution I could think of was bundling EVERYTHING. it all seems to unnecessarily complicated, and there is a hell of a lot to bundle (not to mention the overhead), but it seems like I have no other choice - might as well turn most of the components into a service, since that's probably the right way to do things anyway...

Answer (score 0):

If you return `Service.START_STICKY;` in your Service's `onStartCommand`, it it should restart in case your app gets terminated. So if you have any code that you want to run for a longer period of time, put it in a service.

Here's an example:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    registerAlarmBroadcast();

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid re-writing things. I barely know what I did as it is. If I move my code to a service, I'll have to figure out how to interact with the UI, and I'm trying to avoid any more complications - but then, I might have no choice (but I'd like to be sure of that first)

Comment: I understand - just remember that the Android can at any point terminate your app if it's just an Activity. Especially if the app just sits in the background and there is no user interaction. However, a Service solves this issue by letting your app run indefinitely in the background. You should look into using an IntentService. It's probably the easiest way of implementing a Service into your app. Google has some awesome documentation too. http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll hold on for a little bit longer, but I suspect there is no answer without using a service (which makes sense to me, but I'm still hoping :P ). I'll look into that meanwhile.